# Ignore input_userauth_banner when running ssh-copy-id

Tags: shell, ssh

I am well aware of the `-q` option of `ssh` to perform the quiet mode as the man page says

> -q      Quiet mode.  Causes most warning and diagnostic messages to be suppressed.

Somehow can I achieve something like this with `ssh-copy-id`? I want to ignore the **input_userauth_banner**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `ssh-copy-id` requires `LogLevel=INFO` to get some information from the `ssh` process. But that does not need to be passed to the user. You should be able to run `ssh-copy-id` silently using

```
ssh-copy-id -o LogLevel=QUIET server
```